# Please explain break and continue on Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

First excuse my newbie question. I am learning Objective C and very new to programming itself.

Can you guys explain me what causes a break or continue inside a loop?

For example, what is the difference between the two codes?

```
 for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
      if ([self okToProceed]) {
         [self doSomething];
      } else {
         break;
      }
  }
```

and

```
  for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
      if ([self okToProceed]) {
         [self doSomething];
      } else {
         continue;
      }
  }
```

Will the first code stop the loop the first time okToProceed returns false and the second loop simply continue to run, but doing nothing when okToProceed is false?

Comment: Note that "break" and "continue" are keywords of the C programming language, on which Objective-C is based. Learning C will definitely help you for the Objective-C programming.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A `break` statement exits the loop.
You can think of it as a means to create loop exit conditions.

For example, in your code: `for(int i=0; i<100; i++)`, `i<100` is a loop condition.
i.e. loop will exit if this condition is not met.

Similarly, inside if you have something like `if(i == 34) { break; }`.
This will exit the loop when value of `i` reaches 34 even though the loop exit condition specified was `i<100`.

---

A `continue` statement is used to skip to the next loop cycle.
This statement is used to basically avoid running the rest of the code within the loop.

Example:

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
   if(i == 3) {
      continue;
   }
   print(i);
}
```

This loop will print `0 1 2 4`.
When `i` will be 3, `continue` will skip to the next loop iteration and the statements after `continue` (*i.e. `print(i);` will not execute*).
Ofcourse, the loop condition is checked before the loop runs.

Comment: Both `break` and `continue` are essentially a form of `goto`. In nested loops `goto` can be used to break or continue a parent loop.

Answer (score 8):

`break` will exit the loop completely, `continue` will just skip the current iteration and will carry on the next one.

For example in your loop in let's say `i` is equal to 50 and you put `break` the loop will exit the loop but if you use `continue` it will skip this iteration and it will start the next one - `i` will be equal 51.